# return zero instead of nothing when no rows in the corresponding index, and slicing from a list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, is-empty

I have two questions:
the first one:
I have the following code

```
count_by_week=df[df['institution_id']==1].groupby(['group_ident','Year','Week'],observed=True, as_index=True)['activity_id','Teacher_ID','school_subject'].nunique()
g=[2332136, 2192823, 2192825]
Y21=[2021]
Y22=[2022]
l21=list(range(30,53,1))
l22=list(range(1,10,1))
for i in g:
    lw=list(itertools.product(i,Y21,l21))+list(itertools.product(i,Y22,l22))
    count_by_week.loc[count_by_week.index.isin(lw),:]
```

I want the following line
`count_by_week.loc[count_by_week.index.isin(lw),:]`
to return 0 instead of nothing when no item in the corresponding year and week.

and the second one :
if I have the following list of tuple with three elements (Id, Year,Week)  :

```
[ (2192825, 2021, 45),
 (2192825, 2021, 46),
 (2192825, 2021, 47),
 (2192825, 2021, 48),
 (2192825, 2021, 49),
 (2192825, 2021, 50),
 (2192825, 2021, 51),
 (2192825, 2021, 52),
 (2192825, 2022, 1),
 (2192825, 2022, 2),
 (2192825, 2022, 3),
]
```

and I want to get the items between week 50 and week 2. is there a way for this?
I tried the following assuming that the above list called lw0 :

```
lw0[lw0.index(week1):lw0.index(week2)]
```

this hadn't works!
Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution for the first question:
the last line should be modified be using reindex() function:

```
count_by_week.loc[count_by_week.index.isin(lw),:].reindex((i for i in lw),fill_value=0)
```

this will make the code return zero when no instances in the corresponding indexes.

Comment: `.reindex((i for i in lw), ...)` should just be `.reindex(lw, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

1st Question.

do you mean this?

```
int(bool(count_by_week.loc[count_by_week.index.isin(lw),:]))
```

2nd Question.
You have to apply more logic here

```
def get_index_from_date(data, year, week):
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        if d[1] == year and d[2] == week:
            return i

lwo[get_index_from_date(2021, 50):get_index_from_date(2022, 2)+1]
```

Comment: your answer for the second question work perfectly, thank you. for the first question, I want the line to return the raw in the datafram which correspond to the index and if no data point corresponding to the index it return zero. the solution you suggest hasn't return any thing. thanks